# Level sets of a maths function in Python

Tags: python, math

Given a function

***f(x, y): ℝ<sup>2</sup> → ℝ***

I want to use Python to find its level sets, that is, ***f <sup>-1</sup>(c)*** for a fixed ***c***.

More generally it would also be helpful to find the set ***{ (x, y): a < f(x, y) < b }*** for fixed ***a, b***.

Is there a function in a library that does this reasonably fast?

P.S. Raising awareness to [the request of having math rendering in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation), which would be useful for this question.

Comment: What format do you expect Python to give the result in, given that there may be infinite solutions, sets of 2D-ranges, each closed or not or part of it. Secondly, see point 4 in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @trincot Thanks for formatting the maths. A numerical approximation is good enough, namely returning coordinates in a mesh / lattice that belongs to the level sets.

Comment: @trincot Re point 4: point taken - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that ***f^{-1}*** is not given?

Comment: Check out [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

Comment: See http://www.python-course.eu/matplotlib_contour_plot.php and similar [tutorials on using contour plots in `matplotlib`.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html)

Comment: @trincot Yep. f is given, but f^{-1} is the inverse of f and not given explicitly.